# How do I add social sharing buttons?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I am on Wordpress and I can easily add a plugin, but that increases load time, looks common and old.

I am using the Brook theme, which a minimal theme. (http://www.defensionem.com/7th-and-3rd-fleet-to-be-combined/)

If you notice, only end at the blog I have my sharing options, Such as Facebook, Linkedin, Twitter.

Can I enable this in the Sidebar widget? I contacted my theme author and they said to me,

> "Our social-sharing links are built in brook/share_block.php. You
>   could try creating a new custom widget, and use the code from
>   share_block.php. Alternatively, you could use a Text Widget, and input
>   directly html code for sharing. By using the markup and classes as we
>   did, you should be able to get the same style."

Here's my that php file. I tried various methods but it did not work. Guess everything is wrong.

Can you all help?

```
<?php

$theme_settings = brook_theme_settings();

if( has_post_thumbnail() ){
    $share_image            = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'xxl' );
    $share_image            = $share_image[0];
    $share_image_portrait   = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'portrait-m' );
    $share_image_portrait   = $share_image_portrait[0];
}else{
    $share_image            = '';
    $share_image_portrait   = '';
}

$share_excerpt = strip_tags( get_the_excerpt(), '<b><i><strong><a>' );


?>

<div class="social-nav social-nav--titles">

    <ul class="social-nav__items">


        <?php if( $theme_settings['sharing_email'] ): ?>
            <li class="social-nav__item">
                <a title="<?php _e( 'Email', 'brook' ); ?>" class="social-nav__link js-skip-ajax" href="mailto:?subject=<?php echo ( rawurlencode( get_the_title() ) ); ?>&amp;body=<?php echo ( rawurlencode ( $share_excerpt . ' ' . get_the_permalink() ) ); ?>">
                    <?php _e( 'Email', 'brook' ); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if( $theme_settings['sharing_facebook'] ): ?>
            <li class="social-nav__item">
                <a title="<?php _e( 'Facebook', 'brook' ); ?>" class="social-nav__link js-sharer js-skip-ajax" target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo( rawurlencode( get_the_permalink() ) ); ?>">
                    <?php _e( 'Facebook', 'brook' ); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if( $theme_settings['sharing_twitter'] ): ?>
            <li class="social-nav__item">
                <a title="<?php _e( 'Twitter', 'brook' ); ?>" class="social-nav__link js-sharer js-skip-ajax" target="_blank"  href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<?php echo( rawurlencode( get_the_title() ) ); ?>&amp;url=<?php echo( rawurlencode( get_the_permalink() ) ); ?>">
                    <?php _e( 'Twitter', 'brook' ); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if( $theme_settings['sharing_pinterest'] ): ?>
            <li class="social-nav__item">
                <a title="<?php _e( 'Pinterest', 'brook' ); ?>" class="social-nav__link js-sharer js-skip-ajax" target="_blank" href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo( rawurlencode( get_the_permalink() ) ); ?>&amp;media=<?php echo ( rawurlencode( $share_image_portrait ) ); ?>&amp;description=<?php echo( rawurlencode( get_the_title() ) ); ?>">
                    <?php _e( 'Pinterest', 'brook' ); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if( $theme_settings['sharing_google'] ): ?>
            <li class="social-nav__item">
                <a title="<?php _e( 'Google+', 'brook' ); ?>" class="social-nav__link js-sharer js-skip-ajax" target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo( rawurlencode( get_the_permalink() ) ); ?>">
                    <?php _e( 'Google+', 'brook' ); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if( $theme_settings['sharing_linkedin'] ): ?>
            <li class="social-nav__item">
                <a title="<?php _e( 'LinkedIn', 'brook' ); ?>" class="social-nav__link js-sharer js-skip-ajax" target="_blank" href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=<?php echo( rawurlencode( get_the_permalink() ) ); ?>&amp;title=<?php echo( rawurlencode( get_the_title() ) ); ?>&amp;summary=<?php echo ( rawurlencode ( $share_excerpt ) );?>&amp;source=<?php echo ( rawurlencode( get_bloginfo('name') ) );?>">
                    <?php _e( 'LinkedIn', 'brook' ); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: have you try creating a shortcode that will echo all the above HTML code? https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well What I suggest you which is the easiest solution is first install a plugin from this link https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-widget/ 
 It ia a plugin when you activate it, it creates a widget in which you can put your all php code from your required file. As far as the styling is concerned you can add the relevant styling to main css file of your Brook theme. I hope it helps....

Comment: Thank you so much Muhammad! Can you just tell which all PHP to add? (I am very new to PHP).

Comment: From your  share_block.php file.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm! Its super awesome. Check my site. http://www.defensionem.com/7th-and-3rd-fleet-to-be-combined/ All I have to do is to edit the apperence a little. Works. Thank you. :)

Comment: U Welcome..Hope you could  easily edit the appearance of a title...You can empty the title field of your widget, and put your title in below textarea..then you can style it accordingly..

Answer (score 0):

Try to social share plugin and put shortcode.